# How do I install the matching kernel sources for raspbian?

Tags: kernel

After spending a lot of time with the presumably correct kernel source for my RPi in order to compile a driver (kernel sources for the driver module and the built kernel need to match precisely, settings included) I gave up and decided to start from scratch, so I downloaded the latest Raspbian image that has kernel `3.18.7+`.  If I understand that correctly, the `+` means that there are additional commits on the top of the `3.18.7` kernel release, so I can't simply download those sources, because the driver would fail.

How can I download the correct kernel sources for this build?

Comment: Just to get this straight: is this driver a normal in-tree driver, or did you download source from some 3rd party?

Comment: It's not a driver that is included in the kernel, it's from a third party.

Comment: Where are you getting the kernel source from?  A distro package, or github?

Comment: I fixed with rpi-source. I was getting them via github.

Comment: You should answer your own question to help others who may have a  similar problem.